# Is there a way to include Groupby inside mutate

Tags: r

I have a dataframe

```
df2
       Date Var Value
1 27/9/2019   A    56
2 28/9/2019   A    50
3 1/10/2019   A    90
4 2/10/2019   B   100
```

I tried to include group by inside mutate. But not able to. What I need is

```
df1
       Date Var Value   mean
1 27/9/2019   A    56   65.3
2 28/9/2019   A    50   65.3
3 1/10/2019   A    90   65.3 
4 2/10/2019   B   100   100
```

I tried with below code but did not get. Actually I need this to be done under summarise only. Is there a way?

```
df1 <- df2 %>% mutate(mean = group_by(Var) %>% summarise(mean(Value)))
```

Comment: Hi thanks. I am aware of this code. But it returns only mean. But I need those value columns as well. you can refer my expected output

Comment: BTW you can do `df2 %>% group_by(Var) %>% mutate(mean = mean(Value))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
df2 %>% 
  group_by(Var) %>% 
  mutate(Mean = mean(Value))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `ave` from `base R`

```
df2$Mean <- with(df2, ave(Value, Var))
```